# JSON response object could not be displayed

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a WCF service that returns a record from my database..I get the value from my WCF using an ajax call to it and get it as an JSON object..

**The below image shows the response object in my browser..**

[image]

That is fine..but when i want to give it using an alert like

```
alert(myData.version);
```

I could not get the values of it.. How do i get the values from my response ??

**MY AJAX CALL :**

```
$.ajax({

                url: urlToHandler,
                type: 'POST',
                data:{},
               dataType:'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {    

myData = ((data.GetUpdateVersionResult), function (key, value) {
    var type;
    if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
        type = value.type;
        if (typeof type === 'string' && typeof window[type] === 'function') {
            return new (window[type])(value);
        }
    }

    return value;
});

alert(myData[0].version);

},
                    error: function(data, status, jqXHR) {                       
                        alert('There was an error.');
                    }
                }); // end $.ajax



    }
```

Comment: Can you add your ajax call so we can see it.

Comment: `alert(myData[0].version);`

Comment: @Antony your comment should be an answer...

Comment: I GET THIS ERROR MESSAGE TypeError: myData[0] is undefined..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info you are looking for is in `data`.

```
alert(data.GetUpdateVersionResult[0].version)
```

Comment: I GET THIS ERROR MESSAGE
TypeError: myData[0] is undefined...

Comment: @praveengodfrey Do `console.log(myData)`. What does it say?

Comment: I have updated with my ajax call too to have a better idea !!

Comment: @praveengodfrey Replace `alert(myData[0].version);` with `console.log(myData);` and tell us what it says in the console.

Comment: I get the respone in my browser only...But cant get it into my alert !!

Comment: Even console.log Gives my respone object in my browser...

Comment: @praveengodfrey Can you **just** tell us what it says in the console? I need to know what is wrong so that I can get this to the alert.

Comment: It just gives function()...on clicking it ,it takes me to my main.html at where the method is implemented

Comment: It takes me to this line when clickin on function()

myData = ((data.GetUpdateVersionResult), function (key, value) {

Comment: @praveengodfrey So what about `console.log(data.GetUpdateVersionResult[0].version)`?

Comment: Yeah...got it right buddy...i can get exactly what i wanted..

THANKS A LOT !!!